# How to lock scrollbar when copying and pasting?

Tags: automation, scroll, scrollbar, autohotkey, copy-paste

Hi all this may be a bit of a vague question.

I am currently trying to automate work that involves a lot of Copying and pasting. Frequently I use the CTRL + SHIFT + END command to quickly highlight text from the start to the end of the document.

Using AutoHotKey I have found a way to automate this process. However, my problem now is that the frequent CTRL + SHIFT + END commands cause the scroll bar jump all the way to the bottom after which my script copies the text and quickly returns me to my previous position.

Doing so is quite dizzying and annoying, and as such I was wondering if anyone knew a way to prevent or lock the scrollbar while doing this?

Comment: Couple of questions if you don't mind. What applications are you using this in? What have you tried so far? you might be able to automate the process through COM objects instead of sending keys, which is why I ask.

Comment: Hi T_Lube! I am currently using Autohotkey for the script, but I am trying to be flexible with regards to where it can be used (I.E notepad, text boxes in chrome, word, etc)

Comment: Ok. Well with some things like notepad you might try ControlGetText to read the control, but it will get the whole of the text. Use WinSpy to determine the control name. Just an idea.

Comment: For random applications, the function will need to bring the bottom text into the viewport so there is little you can do.  For apps with COM or API controls, there is often a "`DisplayOff`" parameter that would do it. With AutoHotKey you could maybe take a screen shot `{Alt+PrtScr}`, overlay that image on your window, do the process behind the image (make sure it is on top in z-order), then destroy the image when you are done.